# Installing rails 12.04 error

Tags: 12.04, ruby, rails, rvm

I have followed all stapes from this page https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

It all goes well until command to install rails

```
gem install rails
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord-deprecated_finders)
```

ON each new try error message shows different gem dependencies?gems=.......

Any advices on this issue?

EDIT:

Here is the full stack trace after executing coomand `gem install rails -V`

```
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
HEAD http://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
HEAD http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=railties
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=railties
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=railties
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=railties
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activesupport
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activesupport
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activesupport
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activesupport
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activemodel
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activemodel
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activemodel
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activemodel
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=sprockets-rails
302 Moved Temporarily
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=sprockets-rails)
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you running? "ruby -v"

Comment: @shtuff.it Ruby 2.1.0

Comment: try adding a -V to get some verbose output. "gem install rails -V"

Comment: @shtuff.it please see the edit.

Comment: are you able to resolve the host or download the link supplied outside of gem? "wget https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=sprockets-rails"

Comment: @shtuff.it I download the dependencies.bin when I click on the link. I an not sure is that you are asking?

Comment: Are you able to download the dependencies.bin from the system that you are trying to install rails on? Wondering is the system has an issue resolving the host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed rails last week using the instructions here:

http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html

### Notable differences between the how-to's are:

the addition of the `--ruby` to the command:

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

The command to updating RVM is instead:

`rvm get stable --autolibs=enable`

The version of ruby to use is explicitly set:

`rvm --default use ruby-2.1.0`

**Installation of js.Node**

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

The installation of rails is also preceded by explicitly setting the version:

`rvm use ruby-2.1.0@rails4.0 --create`